# Stress in rotating 'rigid' body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, centrifugal-force, stress-strain

I have some trouble understanding the rotating rigid body motion. Consider a cube made of very high elastic modulus homogeneous material (which can be approximated as 'rigid' body), it is rotating about axis-z with constant spin speed $\Omega$.
[image]

I wonder if the is internal stress or strain in the cube, and if
it is possible to compute them.

Here are my thoughts:

Consider a general point $P$ in this cube. When the cube is rotating, its position is different from its initial position because of the centrifugal force. Hence it is possible for internal strain to exist. However, if the body is very 'rigid' it is very small. I don't know how to express it in a general way, in terms of the centrifugal force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal stress in the cube does exists - it keeps the cube from falling apart due to the rotation or, we can say, due to the centrifugal forces.

The diagram below shows a possible way to estimate the stress at any given point $P$ inside the cube.

[image]

The force (stress) acting on an infinitesimally narrow vertical slice around point $P$ is equal to the centripetal force $F$ that keeps a narrow segment of the cube (shown in pink) from flying away.

$$F=m\Omega^2R_{\rm CM}$$

where $m$ is the mass of the segment and $R_{\rm CM}$ is the distance from the center of rotation to the segment's center of mass.